# Is It possible to make such calculation and return this result with MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm pretty new to MongoDB. consider the following collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("c0c672fa6db9b3f954732b1a"),
"date" : ISODate("2016-11-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
"statistics" : {
    "members" : {
        "topPerformers" : {
            "hours" : [ 
                {
                    "workHour" : 10,
                    "Darth Vader" : 72,
                    "Walrus Man" : 80,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 60
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 11,
                    "Darth Vader" : 142,
                    "Walrus Man" : 115,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 100
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 12,
                    "Darth Vader" : 116,
                    "Walrus Man" : 81,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 113
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 13,
                    "Darth Vader" : 128,
                    "Walrus Man" : 90,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 141
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 14,
                    "Darth Vader" : 95,
                    "Walrus Man" : 118,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 116
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 15,
                    "Darth Vader" : 91,
                    "Walrus Man" : 93,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 124
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 16,
                    "Darth Vader" : 144,
                    "Walrus Man" : 95,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 111
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 17,
                    "Darth Vader" : 143,
                    "Walrus Man" : 72,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 136
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 18,
                    "Darth Vader" : 54,
                    "Walrus Man" : 88,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 87
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 19,
                    "Darth Vader" : 82,
                    "Walrus Man" : 146,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 67
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 20,
                    "Darth Vader" : 88,
                    "Walrus Man" : 136,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 52
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 21,
                    "Darth Vader" : 92,
                    "Walrus Man" : 113,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 124
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 22,
                    "Darth Vader" : 91,
                    "Walrus Man" : 68,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 128
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 23,
                    "Darth Vader" : 125,
                    "Walrus Man" : 64,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 84
                }, 
                {
                    "workHour" : 0,
                    "Darth Vader" : 97,
                    "Walrus Man" : 108,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 75
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Each record of 1 day looks like this, for example I have 30 documents in the collection for each day. I am able to do `db.getCollection('name').find({ date: { $gte: new ISODate(), $lt: new ISODate() } })` with the date range I want, then If I'm selecting the records of the whole month, I can loop over `statistics.members.topPerformers.hours` and calculate the total for each member during that day in the client side with Javascript like so:

```
statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.forEach((hour) => {
          Object
            .keys(hour)
            .filter(key => key !== 'workHour')
            .forEach((key) => {
              result[key] = (result[key] || 0) + hour[key];
            });
        });
```

Can I do it server side with Mongo and return modified result like this one for example:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("c0c672fa6db9b3f954732b1a"),
"date" : ISODate("2016-11-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
"statistics" : {
    "members" : {
        "topPerformers" : {
            "hours" : [ 
                {
                    "workHour" : 10,
                    "Darth Vader" : 2512,
                    "Walrus Man" : 1423,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 1487
                }, 
             ]
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: You should be able to use aggregation with a pipeline similar to [match, group, unwind, group] to get the results you are looking for.

Will check back later to see if anyone has expanded this comment but if not I can try and give an example when I have a bit of time.

match whatever you want, group by date, unwind statistics.members.topPerformers.hours, group how you want to get the output format

Answer (score 0):

You could run an aggregation pipeline that makes use of the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator pipeline stage to filter the documents in the collection by given date range, the preceding **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator to flatten the embedded hours array which you can then group the denormalised documents using the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline and calculate the sums.

The following mongo shell operation demonstrates the above:

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end } } },
    { "$unwind": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "date": { "$first": "$date" },
            "workHour" : { 
                "$sum": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.workHour" 
            },
            "Darth Vader" : { 
                "$sum": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Darth Vader" 
            },
            "Walrus Man" : { 
                "$sum": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Walrus Man" 
            },
            "Imperial Stromtrooper" : { 
                "$sum": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Imperial Stromtrooper" 
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("c0c672fa6db9b3f954732b1a"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-11-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "workHour" : 231.0,
    "Darth Vader" : 1560.0,
    "Walrus Man" : 1467.0,
    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 1518.0
}
```

---

Although not necessary, you can reshape the final document fields by appending a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline as follow

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end } } },
    { "$unwind": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "date": { "$first": "$date" },
            "workHour" : { 
                "$sum": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.workHour" 
            },
            "Darth Vader" : { 
                "$sum": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Darth Vader" 
            },
            "Walrus Man" : { 
                "$sum": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Walrus Man" 
            },
            "Imperial Stromtrooper" : { 
                "$sum": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Imperial Stromtrooper" 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "date": 1,
            "statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.workHour": "$workHour",,
            "statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Darth Vader": "$Darth Vader",
            "statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Walrus Man": "$Walrus Man",
            "statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Imperial Stromtrooper": "$Imperial Stromtrooper"
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("c0c672fa6db9b3f954732b1a"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-11-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "statistics" : {
        "members" : {
            "topPerformers" : {
                "hours" : {
                    "workHour" : 231.0,
                    "Darth Vader" : 1560.0,
                    "Walrus Man" : 1467.0,
                    "Imperial Stromtrooper" : 1518.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! the keys inside the values are unknown. so I cannot "Darth Vader" : { 
                "$sum": "$statistics.members.topPerformers.hours.Darth Vader" 
            }, for example, should I stick to client side workaround like I did now? It's taking about 1second to generate the result I need, will Mongo generate it faster?

Comment: If the keys are unknown then the above solution won't be helpful unless you change your schema. Otherwise your client-side workaround should be ok for small datasets but may suffer from performance penalties when you are faced with a lot of documents or subdocuments.

Comment: Could you tell be what would be alot of documents in numbers?

Comment: All I can say is your client-side workaround has a nested for-loop and thus its runtime is `O(N^2)`